# Discard MV-Store in existing H2 Database

Tags: database, h2

Our application uses H2 DB with mv-store storage engine. Due to stability and corruption issues we've decided to discard the use of MV-Store.

Is there a way to use existing database file *.mv.db with 'mv_store=false' or 'mvcc=false' in the db url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you would need to migrate the database. You could do this by exporting to a SQL file, and then creating a new database and import from this SQL file. To create a SQL script, you could use the `SCRIPT` command, and to import, run the `RUNSCRIPT` command. There are tool available as well (`Script` and `RunScript`).

As for the corruption, I suggest to provide more details in the H2 mailing list, if you didn't do that so far. The reason is, the MVStore is supposed to be the next generation store.

Comment: Thanks for the response and the Great Wok, hats off!
Furthermore, is there a way to use existing *.h2.db files with 1.4.xxx versions of H2 without using the 'mv-store=fale' or 'mvcc=false' in the db url?

Comment: If a database file with the name *.h2.db already exists, then the PageStore format is automatically used, without you having to specify this. In this case, the default is 'mvcc=false'. The MVStore is only used if no database file exists.

Comment: Thanx a lot, it helps.